# My Python Selenium code doesn't work with options

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i'm using a selenium code in spyder 3.8 with anaconda. The issue is that it works perfectly when i don't add any option to the driver, it goes to the url and click the thins it has to, but for some reason when i add options it just opens the browser, but doesn't go to the url and can't continue with the code. This is weird because i tried running this code on 2 other pc's with spyder 3.7 and an older version and it runs perfectly with the options.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this, thanks for your attention!

````
import pandas as pd 
import zipfile
import os
import datetime 
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as W
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import win32com.client as win32
import re
import glob
from datetime import date, timedelta
from openpyxl import load_workbook #usar este en vez de pd para el loop
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import win32com.client
from zipfile import ZipFile







driver_path = 'C:/Users/amoralesv/Desktop/dchrome/chromedriver'   

link_gener = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/graficos/operacion-real/generacion-real-del-sistema/"
link_SIC = "https://www.coordinador.cl/mercados/graficos/costos-marginales/costo-marginal-real/"
link_inf_nov = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/novedades-cdc/"
link_inf_abast = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/estudios-de-la-programacion-de-la-operacion/programacion-mensual/"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions--') 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\amoralesv\\Downloads",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}) #Hace que el pdf se descargue y no se abra en pestaña



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = chrome_options) 

def descarga_generacion(mes, año, mes_pasado, año_pasado, driver):
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(link_gener)
    wait = W(driver, 20)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tipo-xlsx"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tipo-xlsx"))).click()
    time.sleep(9)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker777-9761_2"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(mes)
    dropdown_year = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_year.select_by_visible_text(año)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-marginal']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker777-9761_2"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(mes_pasado)
    dropdown_year = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_year.select_by_visible_text(año_pasado)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-marginal']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)
    
    
    
def descarga_SIC_SING(nombre,nombre2, driver):
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(link_SIC)
    wait = W(driver, 20)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker22-9773"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))))
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(nombre)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-costos']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)   
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker22-9773"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))))
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(nombre2)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-costos']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)   ```
````

Comment: Is there an error message you are seeing? I noticed you have 2 functions defined but you are not calling either of them after your driver initialization.

Comment: I call the functions further in the code, but i'm sure that's not the problem. I don't get any error unless i stop the code in the console, in that case i sometimes get ""WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)"

Comment: Ensure your chromedriver version is up to date and compatible with your Chrome browser version, mismatch can cause issues sometimes. And you could try passing options as `chrome_options=chrome_options` instead of `options=chrome_options`

Comment: I checked the chromedriver version and its the right one for the chrome version, they are both the same as in the pc's that the code works well. I tried doing chrome_options instead of options as you said and i got this error and warning:  DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, chrome_options = chrome_options)  and then the error: WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist. This time it didn't even open the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic entry in your options is:

```
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
```

I'd recommend use this one instead:

```
"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}]
```

It does the same thing; allows pdf files to be downloaded instead of showing them.