# Python selenium code doesn't work with options on my pc

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

i have a **webscraping** code in python (spyder 3.8) with selenium, where i need to click several buttons in some url to download some files. I've tried my code on 2 differente pc's and it works perfectly, but when i run it on my office pc it doesn't and i need to be able to run it there.
The problem is that when i add options on the chromedriver, the code just opens the browser, but then it does nothing, it doesn't go to the url and after some time it says the error "WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist". If i run it without any options it does work, but i need to include them.

I already checked the chrome version to be compatible with the driver and tried running the code without any options and it does work. Besides, if i use driver.get directly instead of WebDriverGet, it seems to work with options, but i need to use WebDriverWait in order to make a more stable code, i really don't know what the problem can be :(. Thanks for your attention!

````
import pandas as pd 
import zipfile
import os
import datetime 
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as W
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import win32com.client as win32
import re
import glob
from datetime import date, timedelta
from openpyxl import load_workbook #usar este en vez de pd para el loop
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import win32com.client
from zipfile import ZipFile







driver_path = 'C:/Users/amoralesv/Desktop/dchrome/chromedriver'   

link_gener = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/graficos/operacion-real/generacion-real-del-sistema/"
link_SIC = "https://www.coordinador.cl/mercados/graficos/costos-marginales/costo-marginal-real/"
link_inf_nov = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/novedades-cdc/"
link_inf_abast = "https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/estudios-de-la-programacion-de-la-operacion/programacion-mensual/"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions--') 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\amoralesv\\Downloads",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}) #Hace que el pdf se descargue y no se abra en pestaña



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = chrome_options) 

def descarga_generacion(mes, año, mes_pasado, año_pasado, driver):
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(link_gener)
    wait = W(driver, 20)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tipo-xlsx"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tipo-xlsx"))).click()
    time.sleep(9)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker777-9761_2"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(mes)
    dropdown_year = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_year.select_by_visible_text(año)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-marginal']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker777-9761_2"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-month"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(mes_pasado)
    dropdown_year = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-datepicker-year"))))
    time.sleep(1)
    dropdown_year.select_by_visible_text(año_pasado)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-marginal']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)
    
    
    
def descarga_SIC_SING(nombre,nombre2, driver):
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(link_SIC)
    wait = W(driver, 20)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker22-9773"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))))
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(nombre)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-costos']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)   
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "datepicker22-9773"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='ui-priority-primary']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))).click()
    dropdown_month = Select(wait.until(E.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "barras-costos"))))
    dropdown_month.select_by_visible_text(nombre2)
    download =  wait.until(E.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='download-file-costos']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download)   ```
````

Comment: I can't help with your question specifically, so I won't answer but I HIGHLY SUGGEST you get rid of all these `time.sleep()`s since you have an `implicitWait()` built in. Your driver will do the sleeps/waits for you. There's about 15-20 lines of code here that you can just get rid of.

Comment: also, do not mix implicit and explicit waits.  Those will be competing polling loops.   The error "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" suggests that the browser was not able to save the file with the sessionID that the webdriver needs.  That suggests that a previous run of the driver has hung, or the browser is not launching correctly... or with proper permissions for the user/profile it is launching.  (there are other causes for this... but if you are running multiple drivers one after another or concurrently make sure to include a wait after closing one driver and beginning a new one.)

Comment: the error appears even the first time i run the code, its weird that if i dont use options it does run propperly. The problem appears when i use the remot pc of my job, maybe it has some restrictions but it doesnt make sense because if i dont use options it does work., so it has to be something with anaconda or spyder. I couldn't download them directly from the pc, i had to paste it from my personal pc ¿Maybe that's the issue? I installed propperly selenium tho

Comment: I'd check Chrome.   Be sure to run it using the same user you are running the script with.  (Sometimes you'll just need to make sure it runs once so it initializes all the directories...)  Also gives you a chance to check the version and make sure it matches the major version of the webdriver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Python Selenium code doesn't work with options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647801/my-python-selenium-code-doesnt-work-with-options)